# how do we store Segmented Image template in the Matlab for matching?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, template-matching, iris-recognition

I am beginner in the MATLAB. I am working on the iris segmentation and recognition for my research work. I have used the Libor Masek (http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/studentprojects/libor/sourcecode.html - Source Code available here).
Whole Process Report - (http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/studentprojects/libor/LiborMasekThesis.pdf)

It gives me the template and mask of the segmented iris image in the createiristemplate.m file. 
I have to perform this segmentation over the large image set of database and i require that individual image template and mask should be stored in some way (like file, array or else) for further Matching procedure.

I could not be able to find a way to store this template in such a way for the further matching.

I require the template must be stored in some file for future matching when another template generated with improved segmentation.

require the answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy solutions are save the array as an m-file using

```
save(filename, 'template', 'mask');
```

or save to text using

```
dlmwrite(filename, template);
dlmwrite(filename, mask);
```

when you want to do further analysis you can reopen them with `load()` or `dlmread()`